# C++ macro string concatenation

Tags: c++, macros

This macro seems to replace SNMPWRITEFUNC(w,x,y,z,q) with a function returning a static type
SNMPWriteObject, but perhaps it is instead an overload of a SNMPWriteObject method? Quite obscure to me, so I would be grateful for the help of one more experienced in this area!

```
#define SNMPWRITEFUNC(w,x,y,z,q) static SNMPWriteObject R##w(x,y,z,q);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's just a convenience macro for generating a number of similar function prototypes, so if you write e.g.

```
SNMPWRITEFUNC(foo,int,int,int,int)
SNMPWRITEFUNC(bar,char,float,char,float)
SNMPWRITEFUNC(blech,int,char,float,int)
```

it will be expanded to:

```
static SNMPWriteObject Rfoo(int,int,int,int);
static SNMPWriteObject Rbar(char,float,char,float);
static SNMPWriteObject Rblech(int,char,float,int);
```

Note that `##` is commonly known as the [token pasting operator](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html).

Note also that the macro and examples above are not C++-specific - this could just as easily be C code.